# Set up a php proxy to access censored websites and bypass firewall

Tags: php, curl

I'm currently using this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/repress/ which basically makes my website a proxy so that users can access censored websites like this

```
www.mywebsite.com/proxy/www.cnn.com
```

The plugin works well enough but when it comes to absolute links the plugin doesn't parse it properly and the link is still blocked. That plugin development has stopped. So I need to write my own script. I've been searching everywhere and reading up on the tutorials I can find but none specifically helps me in regards to this.

I know how to use php curl to fetch a website and echo it on a blank page. What I don't know is how to set a proxy script to work like the above example where users can type

```
www.mywebsite.com
```

followed by

```
/proxy.php
```

then their target website

```
/www.cnn.com
```

Currently I have this set up:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.cnn.com';
$proxy_port = 80;
$proxy = '92.105.140.115';
$timeout = 0;
$referer = 'http://www.mydomain.com'


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data; 
?>
```

This pulls the home page but no css or images are retrieved. Likewise all relative links are broken. I have no idea how to apply the proxy_port and proxy variables. I tried

```
92.105.140.115:80/www.cnn.com
```

but that doesn't work. I don't quite fully understand this code either since I found it on an example site.

Any answer or links for tutorials is greatly welcome.

Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have a completely functioning proxy isn't that simple. There are many such projects already available. Give any a shot:

- http://www.surrogafier.info/
- https://github.com/Alexxz/Simple-php-proxy-script
- http://www.glype.com/

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

you can not just echo in a page the result of a curl's fetch website because the browsers will interpret the Uris bad, you need that when the user click on a link he goes to your proxy site not to the original site, so you can't just print with echo, you need to  edit manual every link in that fetched page before print it to the users, i have a full functional proxy made by php en p.listascuba.com you cant try it.

contact me for more info